# Creating $elemMatch query with multiple $regex clauses in python and mongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I am implementing this tutorial [How to Speed-Up MongoDB Regex Queries by a Factor of up-to 10](https://medium.com/statuscode/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-regex-queries-by-a-factor-of-up-to-10-73995435c606)
and I am using the query specified at the end

```
db.movies.find({
$and:[{
    $text: {
        $search: "Moss Carrie-Anne"
    }},{
    cast: {
        $elemMatch: {$regex: /Moss/, $regex: /Carrie-Anne/}}
    }]}
);
```

The problem where I am stuck with is how do I generate the sub-query

```
$elemMatch: {$regex: /Moss/, $regex: /Carrie-Anne/}
```

programmatically with python

My code so far

```
def regexGen(s):
  d={}
  for word in s.split(" "):
    d["$regex"]= "/"+word+"/"  # this will of course save only the last value into the dict

  return (d)


query= {
    "$and":[{
        "$text": {
            "$search": "Moss Carrie-Anne"
        }},{
        "cast": {
            "$elemMatch": regexGen("Moss Carrie-Anne")}
        }
    ]
}

print (query)

#actual
# {'$and': [{'$text': {'$search': 'Moss Carrie-Anne'}}, {'cast': {'$elemMatch': {'$regex': '/Carrie-Anne/'}}}]}

#expected
# {'$and': [{'$text': {'$search': 'Moss Carrie-Anne'}}, {'cast': {'$elemMatch': {'$regex': '/Carrie-Anne/'}, {'$regex': '/Moss/'} }}]}
```

I am obviously missing something here, but not able to figure out

Comment: Try `def regexGen(s): return [("$regex", re.compile(re.escape(word))) for word in s.split()]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This doesn't produce the output as expected. Please do note, that I need to send this back to pymongo driver.

Comment: Well, probably a list of regexes will be accepted, try `d = {}`, `d["$regex"] = []`, `for word in s.split():`, `d["$regex"].append(re.compile(re.escape(word)))`. See https://ideone.com/EEDYF9

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your way, It raises an error-  pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $elemMatch needs an Object

Comment: Ok, the easiest: create an alternation based regex to match any word: `{ "$regex" : "|".join([re.escape(word) for word in s.split()]) }`. To only look for whole words, `{ "$regex" : r"(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)".format("|".join([re.escape(word) for word in s.split()])) }` (or `r"(?<!\S)(?:{})(?!\S)"` to match in between whitespace only).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this approach { "$regex" : "|".join([re.escape(word) for word in s.split()]) } worked. I was very single minded looking to generate the exact query which the author of the article which I had shared was using. Your approach is obviously better, and it works at my end. If you would like to put this in a proper answer I will accept it! Thanks for not giving up on the n00b me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build a dynamic regex based on [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
{ "$regex" : "|".join([re.escape(word) for word in s.split()]) }
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YofYOB):

```
import re
s = "Moss Carrie-Anne"
print({ "$regex" : "|".join([re.escape(word) for word in s.split()]) })
# => {'$regex': 'Moss|Carrie\-Anne'}
```

Note that `Moss|Carrie\-Anne` will match either `Moss` or `Carrie-Anne`. `re.escape` will be helpful if you have `(`, `+` and other regex special chars in your literal input.